# How to build a test group in watir?

Tags: unit-testing, watir

I have some single watir.rb scripts that use IE and are written in a standard watir way.

How do I create a `test group` that combines them? I want all of them be executed by executing the main script.

Is it possible to auto include single test files into a test group by subidr?

Is it possible to enumerate the files that should be included in the test group?

Can I cascade (include other watir test groups in a watir test group)?

*Edit:* After much searching and googling I could not find anything.

I will use this simple style for now:

```
passed = 0
failed = 0

result = system("ruby suite_one.rb")  #execute the script and wait for it to finish.
if result  #Record our results.
  passed = passed + 1
else 
  failed = failed + 1
end


result = system("ruby suite_two.rb")  #execute the script and wait for it to finish.
if result  #Record our results.
  passed = passed + 1
else 
  failed = failed + 1
end

puts "failed: " 
puts failed
puts "passed: " 
puts passed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look how [Watir](http://github.com/bret/watir/) [unit tests](http://github.com/bret/watir/tree/master/commonwatir/unittests/) are executed.

Comment: Thank you. I was not yet able to find what I am looking for, there are a number of files, but I will look harder as soon as I have more time. OP - aka